# Remove subscriber(s) from list via script

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, automationstudio, subscriber

I'm pretty new at SSJS, but I'm trying to run a script in automation studio that removes a subscriber from a list via the unsubscribe function (see: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_listSubscribersUnsubscribe.htm)

The javascript is valid according to Automation Studio and it also runs without error. However, the subscriber is not removed from the list.

My script is as follows and the email address I am referring to exists within the list:

```
Platform.Load("core","1");   
var myList = List.Init("DeleteDelta");      
var status myList.Subscribers.Unsubscribe("totalnonsense@nonsense.com");
```

Hopefully someone can tell me what I am doing wrong!

Comment: you need to remove or unsubscribe the subscriber  from particular list?

Comment: The goal is to remove it from the list (DeleteDelta), which will hopefully result that it is also removed from the all subscribers. According to the link, the unsubscribe function will result in the removal of the subsriber from the list.

Comment: particular subscriber or all subscribers remove from list ?

Comment: I was now testing to remove 1 subscriber, but in the end I want to remove all the subscribers from the list so that they will also be removed/deleted from the all subscribers.

Comment: So, all subscribers from the list

Comment: But I would also like to understand why the current script is not working.

Comment: @pkharries do you have any suggestions?

Comment: check the below answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Rutger Vogelsang this code for deleting all subscriber from particular list

```
  <script runat="server">
 Platform.Load("Core","1");
var  myList = List.Init("external key here");
var listFields = myList.Subscribers.Retrieve();
 var listFieldsLength = listFields.length;
 if (listFieldsLength > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < listFieldsLength; i++) {
 var subObj = Subscriber.Init(listFields[i].SubscriberKey);
   var status = subObj.Remove();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Perfect! This removes subscribers from the list, keeps the list in tact but also removes the subscribers from the all subscriber!

Comment: @Rutger Vogelsang  give  me score for my answer

Answer (score 0):

@Rutger Vogelsang use like this for the above code

```
      <script runat="server" language="javascript">
       Platform.Load("Core","1");


         var myList = List.Init("use list external key here");

        var status = myList.Subscribers.Unsubscribe("galiya123@gmail.com");

           Write(Stringify(status ));

       </script>
```

Comment: thank you very much. I ran the script and it changed the status of the subscriber to unsubscribed.

Is there also a possibility to actually remove the subscriber or, even better, all the subscribers from the list?

Comment: @Rutger Vogelsang make me best answer

Comment: @Rutger Vogelsang this code is working for your requirement  please make me best answer

Comment: @Rutger Vogelsang this is for deleting all subscribers and list also use like this  under list.init                          
                 var subs = myList.Subscribers.Retrieve();
                var status = myList.Remove();